# Set EndpointConfiguration in AWS Lambda serverless.template file

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

AWS API Gateway (relatively) recently allowed the endpoint configuration to be set as Regional instead of Edge Optimized. I am creating serverless lambda functions using .NET.

From what I understand I need to add the following value to set the endpoint type:

```
"EndpointConfiguration": { "Types" : [ "REGIONAL" ] }
```

Does the serverless.template accept this key-value pair and where would I put it?

Edit: I am not using the serverless framework. I'm using the AWS Toolkit in Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say you are using the AWS Toolkit in Visual Studio 2017 I am assuming that you are using AWS SAM and building CloudFormation templates (as inferred by your mention of `serverless.template`).

Currently AWS SAM does not support setting up API Gateways with Regional Endpoints. Here is the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/248) currently tracking it

However, if you are using custom domains there is a reasonable workaround.

You are able to create a `AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName` resource with the Endpoint set to Regional even though your API Gateway was created with the Endpoint set to Edge Optimized.

Below is an example of how I have achieved this in my AWS SAM templates (I use YAML instead of JSON because it's easier to do multiline values).

NOTE: the `AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName` currently does not give out information about Regional Endpoints so I have included a Custom Resource that is able to retrieve the information we need.

```
  MyApiGateway:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Api'
    Properties:
      StageName: 'prod'

  ApiCertificate:
    Type: 'AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate'
    Properties:
      DomainName: 'api.example.com'
      DomainValidationOptions:
      - DomainName: 'api.example.com'
        ValidationDomain: 'example.com'

  CustomResourceLambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: 'lambda.amazonaws.com'
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole'
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: ApiGateway
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Action:
            - 'apigateway:*'
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: '*'

  DomainNameInfoCustomResourceFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt CustomResourceLambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Runtime: 'nodejs6.10'
      Timeout: 300
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
          const response = require('cfn-response');

          exports.handler = function(event, context) {
              const ApiGateway = new AWS.APIGateway();
              ApiGateway.getDomainName({
                  domainName: event.ResourceProperties.DomainName
              }, (err, data) => {
                  if (err != null) {
                      response.send(event, context, response.FAILED, undefined);
                  } else {
                      response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, {
                          DomainName: data.domainName,
                          RegionalDomainName: data.regionalDomainName,
                          RegionalHostedZoneId: data.regionalHostedZoneId,
                          DistributionDomainName: data.distributionDomainName,
                          DistributionHostedZoneId: data.distributionHostedZoneId
                      });
                  }
              });
          }

  ApiDomainName:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName'
    Properties:
      DomainName: 'api.example.com'
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
        - REGIONAL
      RegionalCertificateArn: !Ref ApiCertificate

  ApiBasePathMapping:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping'
    DependsOn: [MyApiGatewayprodStage, ApiDomainName]
    Properties:
      DomainName: 'api.example.com'
      RestApiId: !Ref MyApiGateway
      Stage: 'prod'

  ApiDomainNameInfo:
    Type: 'Custom::DomainNameInfo'
    DependsOn: [ApiDomainName, ApiBasePathMapping]
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt DomainNameInfoCustomResourceFunction.Arn
      DomainName: !Ref ApiDomainName

  ApiRecordSet:
    Type: 'AWS::Route53::RecordSet'
    DependsOn: [ApiDomainNameInfo]
    Properties:
      HostedZoneId: '0123456789' # ENTER YOUR DOMAINS HOSTED ZONE ID
      Name: 'api.example.com'
      ResourceRecords:
      - !GetAtt ApiDomainNameInfo.RegionalDomainName
      Type: CNAME
      TTL: 60
```

Answer (score 0):

See the Serverless Framework [documentation](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#configuring-endpoint-types)

Basically it's `endpointType: REGIONAL`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response, however, I am not using the serverless framework. I'm using the AWS Toolkit in Visual Studio. I've updated my question to reflect that